# SQL rows to pandas with cursor.execute

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to store rows from SQL into a pandas dataframe.
I can't use read_sql because the query updates and read at the same time, and read_sql only reads but don't commit the update.
This is the code I am using:

```
    import pyodbc
    
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server='+self.server+';'
                    'Database='+self.database+';'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_query=f'''
                UPDATE TOP (1) q
                    SET BQ_status = 'Loading'
                    OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.GCS_path, inserted.file_first_upload
                FROM dbo.[Queue] AS q WITH (SERIALIZABLE, ROWLOCK)
                    WHERE q.[BQ_status] IS NULL and q.upload_date IS NOT NULL;
                '''
    cursor.execute(sql_query)

    names = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    pending_files_df=pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=names)
    cursor.commit()
```

These are sample values:

```
names=['Id', 'GCS_path', 'file_first_upload']
rows=[(3113, 'gs://gcmrstr...t', False)]
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1675, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    make_block(
  File "c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2732, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 142, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\AvendanoCr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 584, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "c:\Users\AvendanoCr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 238, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
  File "c:\Users\AvendanoCr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1687, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    raise construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 3)
```

Comment: your rows element is a tuple, not a list. you need to convert it or somehow fetch the data so it's not a tuple. maybe pandas reads a tuple???

Comment: You're right.. it is a list of tuples. That why when I use a type(row) I get "list" as result.